# shutdown, reboot, hibernate notification in leopard using python

Tags: event-handling, osx-leopard

i am developing an application using python that requires to be notified when the system is shutting down, rebooting, hibernating etc. how can I do that?

Please shed some light on this. any hints in Objective C or applescript will be good enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use [defaults](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/defaults) to hook scripts to [login and logout](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/CustomLogin.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002134-SW1), so that might be able to help with hooking shutdown, reboot, etc.  Failing that, check out [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html).

Comment: Thanks that was pretty helpful.